# why an variable defined in a do while loop Cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

**Here is the simple code**

```java
package first;

public class DowhileLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        do {
            int i = 1;
            i++;
            System.out.println("my loop is working ");

        }while(5 > i);
    }
}
```

**Here is the Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
i cannot be resolved to a variable
at todowhileloops/first.DowhileLoops.main(DowhileLoops.java:15)
```

I khow that the variable must be defined outside instead of inside the loop but i want to know whyyyyy... please help and vote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `i` outside do statement. From your current code the scope of `i` is only inside `do{}`. It is a local variable for `do`. It's not accessible to `while()`.

Comment: is there a way to make it global or usable to all the code

Comment: Just define it before do statement. `int i = 0; do{//use i} while(5<i) {//use i};`.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` conditional only has access to "current" variable scope. 
The `do` block creates a "child" variable scope. Any variables declared in a "child" variable scopes are not accessible in "parent" scopes.

See "Loop Scope" in https://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    int i = 1;
    i++;
    System.out.println("my loop is working ");
} while(5 > i);
```

Ok, so first off, you have to initialize the variable outside of the loop itself. so before you write "do {". right now you're setting i to 1 every iteration, meaning this loop will never terminate. Here you go:

```
int i = 0;
do {
    i++
    System.out.println(i);
} while (i < 5);
```